# Quickbook No apptoken detected; (PHP)errorCode=003102; statusCode=401

Tags: quickbooks-online

I am new in quickbooks API implementation, I am always getting  one error `No apptoken detected; errorCode=003102; statusCode=401` when I am doing API call for customer add etc.
I am giving my steps, please look over that.

My sandbox info like that

- Consumer Key: qyprdffbBBInX4a82jG73Mreyy96tC
- Consumer Secret: IgpJzJrYvb9FmmdB7A0ECDGHG62Cp7dqVWjfMTvU
- Access Token: qyprdlo3WrK0KhGZMTeA857AuKiVy2eaAmpXsRvG3jycYaMQ
- Access Token Secret: TdPGpcUI8AiAdWFiCyb8jAAygH16bzU7VRGaspx4

  I am Using PHP.
  First I have generated oauth_signature.

> $URL =
>   rawurlencode('https://sandbox-quickbooks.api.intuit.com/v3/company/408554291/customer');
>   $method = 'POST'; $parameter =
>   rawurlencode('oauth_consumer_key=qyprdffbBBInX4a82jG73Mreyy96tC&oauth_nonce=BlyqIBbv3R4T0P4qglAv1RjoYisMZk1449659733&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1449659733&oauth_token=qyprdlo3WrK0KhGZMTeA857AuKiVy2eaAmpXsRvG3jycYaMQ&oauth_version=1.0');
>
> $ukey =
>   rawurlencode('IgpJzJrYvb9FmmdB7A0ECDGHG62Cp7dqVWjfMTvU').'&'.rawurlencode('TdPGpcUI8AiAdWFiCyb8jAAygH16bzU7VRGaspx4');
>   $hasmac =  hash_hmac("sha1", $BaseURL,$ukey,1);

and My oauth_signature is `jZ8JhECy/e0kpPbUdZp/o/EUC7U=`

When i call API with this oauth_signature, i am getting Error 'No apptoken detected; errorCode=003102; statusCode=401'

My CURL call like this

> curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json, Authorization: OAuth
>   oauth_token=qyprdlo3WrK0KhGZMTeA857AuKiVy2eaAmpXsRvG3jycYaMQ,oauth_consumer_key=qyprdffbBBInX4a82jG73Mreyy96tC,oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1,oauth_timestamp=1449659733,oauth_version=1.0,oauth_nonce=BlyqIBbv3R4T0P4qglAv1RjoYisMZk1449659733,oauth_signature=jZ8JhECy/e0kpPbUdZp/o/EUC7U='
>   -d '{"data": [{"BillAddr":{"Line1":"86 A Topsia","City":"Kolkata","Country":"India","CountrySubDivisionCode":"WB","PostalCode":"700102"},"Title":"Mr.","GivenName":"ApurbaK","MiddleName":"Kumar","FamilyName":"ApurbaK","PrimaryPhone":{"FreeFormNumber":"564545465"},"PrimaryEmailAddr":{"Address":"apurbahazra12@navsoft.in"}}]}'
>   'https://sandbox-quickbooks.api.intuit.com/v3/company/408554291/customer'

Please look over that.

Thanks,
 Apurba

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you don't want to be doing this yourself -- use a library. OAuth is complex, and implementing it yourself is going to be a hairy process, rife with errors.

Go grab a library:

- https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php

Follow the quick-start guide linked there, and benefit from the examples:

- https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php/tree/master/docs/partner_platform/example_app_ipp_v3

With that said, if you do decide to write it yourself, make sure you follow the OAuth spec:

- https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5849

So far, the issues I immediately see with your implementation are:

- You can't hard-code the timestamp like this: `&oauth_timestamp=1449659733` The timestamp should be ever-changing, and set to the currenty timestamp.
- You can't hard-code a nonce like this: `&oauth_nonce=BlyqIBbv3R4T0P4qglAv1RjoYisMZk1449659733` The nonce has to change with *every single request* so this is going to fail after your first request.
- You haven't normalized your request parameters / sorted them, per the spec.
- This is the incorrect way to specify multiple headers with cURL: `-H 'Content-Type: application/json, Authorization: OAuth ...`. Please see the cURL docs: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-H
- In the code you posted, you haven't actually set `$BaseURL` anywhere, so right now you're signing an empty string (unless you forgot to paste some code somewhere?)
- What is `$ukey` set to? It doesn't appear to be defined in your code anywhere (did you forget to paste some code in?)

Comment: @Kaith: Thanks for your answer  i have uploaded my code into server, will u you please look at a glance    http://sample.navigatorssoftware.com/authcode.txt

Comment: This is not correct: curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER,  array('Content-Type: application/json, Authorization: OAuth oauth_token=SYxCE24I/EZcbu3v4J5qGiAvTkg=,oauth_consumer_key=qyprdXOAnzvHkKVQGXiZEKgznFvhXE,oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1,oauth_timestamp='.$timestamp.',oauth_version=1.0,oauth_nonce='.$auth_nonce.',oauth_signature='.$auth_sig.''));   You can't comma-separate headers. Docs: http://php.net/curl_setopt  HTTP headers are separated by newlines, not commas.

Comment: @kaith: i have tried with consolibyte library, it is working authentication and add customer, but i need ales order add to quickbooks from my application, but theere is no example like that, will you please tell me, how can i make extra class like add customer.